# GeoPackage: Nearest point from another table

Tags: geopackage, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to use GeoPackages rather than PostGIS when teaching introductory classes, and that inevitably involves conversions between SQL variants. This time, I'm not able to get to a version of a typical join between one point table and the nearest point in another table. The PostGIS method would be:

```
SELECT
  whc_points.fid,
  closest_pop.fid,
  closest_pop.dist
 FROM whc_points
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
  (SELECT
      fid, 
      ST_Distance(populated_places.geom, whc_points.geom) as dist
      FROM populated_places
      ORDER BY populated_places.geom <-> whc_points.geom
     LIMIT 1
   ) AS closest_pop
```

Looks like CROSS JOIN LATERAL is not supported in GeoPackages. Does anyone have a conversion of this syntax to SQLite syntax?

Comment: You are right, CROSS JOIN LATERAL is not supported by SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html. There is no special GPKG syntax. Spatial functions are available through the SpatiaLite extension https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.